# Nodejs Sequelize.sync() hanging on SHOW INDEX?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When restating our azure server the equalise.sync() method is hanging on the SHOW INDEX of a table it has just created. Even though the table is almost identical to one just created.

**The model for our relation 'Teachers' is as follows:**

```
 'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Teacher = sequelize.define('Teacher', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING
   } , {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Teacher;
};
```

*And this is the code from a student relation that was successfully created, proceeds past SHOW INDEX and does  not cause the script to hang:*

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Student = sequelize.define('Student', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Student;
};
```

*And this is where the code gets up to before hanging/crashing:*

```
d-i89-237-11:IoTSchool-Backend mitchell$ npm start

> express-example@0.0.0 start /Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend
> node ./bin/www

Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Events` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `ename` VARCHAR(255), `edata` VARCHAR(255), `type` INTEGER, `time` VARCHAR(255), `deviceid` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Events` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Schools` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `email` VARCHAR(255), `password` VARCHAR(255), `accessToken` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Schools` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Photons` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(255), `type` VARCHAR(255), `pid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `SchoolId` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolId`) REFERENCES `Schools` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Photons` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `email` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Students` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `username` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Users` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tasks` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `UserId` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Tasks` FROM `IoTSchool`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Teachers` (`teacherid` INTEGER auto_increment , `email` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`teacherid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Tasks` FROM `iotschoolmysql`
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Quit inactivity timeout
at Quit._callback (/Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:104:30)
at Quit.Sequence.end (/Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
at /Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:393:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at /Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:392:13
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Quit inactivity timeout
at Quit._callback (/Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:104:30)
at Quit.Sequence.end (/Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
at /Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:393:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at /Users/mitchell/Documents/deco3801/IoTSchool-Backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:392:13
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```